# Rename column names in Excel

Tags: c++, excel

I have columns with names as `SSS-01\01\2015, SSS-01\02\2015` and so on.

I want to rename these cols as `01\01\2015, 01\02\2015` and so on by removing `"SSS-"`.  Below is the code that I am using.

I have all the required values in the List.  Now how do I save those as column names from cell E to H.

```
chartRange = ws.get_Range("e7", "h7");
int colCount=chartRange.Columns.Count;
List<string> colNames=new List<string>();
for(int c=1;c<colCount;c++)
 {
 if(chartRange!=null)
 {
  string colName = chartRange.Columns[c].Value2;
  string colVal = colName.Remove(0, 10);
  colNames.Add(colVal);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it showing column content as ### ?

Comment: Am able to fetch 01\01\2015 as value and it is being stored in the List colNames.How can i add these list values to cell text